# Why does Laravel-8 removes URL variables after the question mark?

Tags: laravel, url, get, laravel-8

In Laravel 8 I have the following link:

```
<a href="mysite.test/var1?var2=2&var3=3">link</a>
```

The problem I have is that when I follow the link, all the variables after the question mark are deleted and are not received in the controller.
The link redirects to:

```
mysite.test/var1
```

Does someone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: There must have been a redirection that removed the variables. try using the same protocol like `href="//mysite.test/var1?var2=2&var3=3"`

Comment: Try this in your destination url to see if the query is there or not. `dd($query = $request->query())`;

Comment: @ManuelGlez, receive an empty array []
Don't know why Laravel deletes the after question mark variables and not passing nothing to the next page. Even if I try to catch the full url, the controller returns only the first part.

Comment: Probably is your server configuration. I wonder is Apache/Nginx rewriting the url request?

Comment: You could use Laravel debugbar to see what laravel is sending https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: Maybe in the .htaccess file, but is the default Laravel-8 installation config. Cannot understand why.

Comment: Can you share the route?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using **asset** as shown:

```
<a href="{{asset("mysite.test/var1?var2=2&var3=3")}}">link</a>
```